# Remove word from string in oracle query

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have values in table like `(a,b,c,d,e)` and I want to remove any value as mentioned below.

suppose I want to remove `b` then comma(`,`) should move i.e `(a,c,d,e)`. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that all your letters are separated by a single comma, you may use a combination of `replace` and `trim` functions.

```
--Test data
with t(s,r) AS
(
  select 'a,b,c,d,e',   'b'  from dual union all
  select 'a,b,c,d,e',   'e'  from dual union all
  select 'a,b,c,d,e',   'a'  from dual union all
  select 'a,b,c,d,e',   'c'  from dual union all
  select 'a,b,c,d,e',   'd'  from dual union all
  select 'a,bc,c,d,e',  'bc' from dual union all
  select 'ad,bc,c,d,ef','ef' from dual union all
  select 'ad,bc,c,d,ef','ad' from dual
  )
select s, r as to_remove, 
 trim ( both ',' from replace(','||s||',', ','||r||',' ,',') ) removed
from t;

S              TO_REMOVE   REMOVED     
a,b,c,d,e       b            a,c,d,e      
a,b,c,d,e       e            a,b,c,d      
a,b,c,d,e       a            b,c,d,e      
a,b,c,d,e       c            a,b,d,e      
a,b,c,d,e       d            a,b,c,e      
a,bc,c,d,e      bc           a,c,d,e      
ad,bc,c,d,ef    ef           ad,bc,c,d    
ad,bc,c,d,ef    ad           bc,c,d,ef
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use either replace or regex_replace to achieve what you expect in plsql.

```
Select replace(MyTable.MyColumn, 'from value', 'to value') as NewValue from MyTable
```

Comment: How does this answer the question? The OP wants not just to replace a letter, but  the associated commas too. I'm not sure why would someone  upvote.

Answer (score 0):

I borrowed code from Kaushik Nayak and added the regexp_replace mentioned by Khatibzadeh.

```
with t(s,r) AS
(
  select 'a,b,c,d,e',   'b'  from dual union all
  select 'a,b,c,d,e',   'e'  from dual union all
  select 'a,b,c,d,e',   'a'  from dual union all
  select 'a,b,c,d,e',   'c'  from dual union all
  select 'a,b,c,d,e',   'd'  from dual
  )
select 
 trim ( both ',' from replace(','||s||',', ','||r||',' ,',') ) trim_replace,
 regexp_replace(s, '^' || r || ',|,' || r || '$|,' || r, '') regexp_replace
from t
```